# Dyadic Function

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation

[image]
I have the following formula in the beginning of the basics of probability theory. The notes only say that we define this function. What does this function serve to ? What does it tell ? What is 1 and subscript the range? I have really hard time understanding the notation and meanings. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $1_\Omega$ is just a shorthand for $f(x) = 1$ when $x\in\Omega$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x\notin\Omega$. It is known as the indicator function.

Comment: $1$ is the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Thank you so if n is between that range the result will be 1 ? what about (r) ?  @AlexanderJ93

Comment: $r$ is the input to the function, so if $r$ is in that range it will be $1$, otherwise it will be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that function used to prove that every positive measurable function is the limit of a sequence of positive simple functions by setting $f_n(x)=d_n(f(x))$ for any positive measurable function $f$. I'm not sure if it's useful for other things.